# How do I use pipes and variable substitution in a shell script (for toggling haproxy active server)?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a mildly complicated operation that I want to do with Docker, bash, and socat (though I welcome other solutions)

I have a command that looks like this:

```
$ sudo docker run --rm --volumes-from myhaproxy mytest/socat /bin/bash -c 'echo "set weight server/server-A 1" | socat /var/run/haproxy.sock stdio && echo "set weight server/server-B 0" | socat /var/run/haproxy.sock stdio'
```

Which works fine from the command line. If I want to swap A and B I just have to modify the command. However, I want to run this in a shell script that looks something like this:

```
sudo docker run --rm --volumes-from myhaproxy mytest/socat /bin/bash -c 'echo "set weight server/server-$current_server 1" | socat /var/run/haproxy.sock stdio && echo "set weight server/server-$inactive_server 0" | socat /var/run/haproxy.sock stdio'
```

But with single quotes the variable aren't interpreted. I just tried wrapping the `'` in `"` like so

```
sudo docker run --rm --volumes-from myhaproxy mytest/socat /bin/bash -c "'echo "set weight server/server-$current_server 1" | socat /var/run/haproxy.sock stdio && echo "set weight server/server-$inactive_server 0" | socat /var/run/haproxy.sock stdio'"
```

but I get an error

```
unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
```

So how can I send this command in a shell script? (note that I'm using `sh` and not `bash`)

Comment: You're certainly using `bash` inside of your sudo command; it's only `sh` on the outside. If you want it to be `sh` on the inside, you'd need to use `sh -c` instead of `bash -c`. That said, my answer takes advantage of your explicit use of bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need so many quotes:

```
 sudo docker run --rm --volumes-from myhaproxy mytest/socat /bin/bash -c 'echo "set weight server/server-$current_server 1" | socat /var/run/haproxy.sock stdio && echo "set weight server/server-$inactive_server 0" | socat /var/run/haproxy.sock stdio'
```

Can be replaced with:

```
 sudo docker run --rm --volumes-from myhaproxy mytest/socat /bin/bash -c "echo set weight server/server-$current_server 1 | socat /var/run/haproxy.sock stdio && echo set weight server/server-$inactive_server 0 | socat /var/run/haproxy.sock stdio"
```

`echo` prints all its arguments separated by space.

If you need to use other comands where is important to group the arguments in one string you can use double quotes for all, and escape the inner quotes with `\`.

```
 sudo docker run --rm --volumes-from myhaproxy mytest/socat /bin/bash -c "other \"set weight server/server-$current_server 1\" | socat /var/run/haproxy.sock stdio && other \"set weight server/server-$inactive_server 0\" | socat /var/run/haproxy.sock stdio"
```

But this becomes hard to read very quickly, in that case the solution proposed by @CharlesDuffy is better.

Comment: I'd be wary of making a general practice of doing string substitution in generating scripts (as this code does) -- passing `"| rm -rf /"` to this script as a server name would lead to code one might not want running as root being executed under `sudo`.

Comment: I totally missed the docker in `sudo docker run` - this command will be run inside of a docker container. And the command itself gets shoved through docker - I wasn't able to get your version working, @CharlesDuffy, but I did get Fernando's working - I just have quotes on the outermost arguments and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh. Running in docker does indeed make the security issues less of a concern -- I'm much more comfortable with this answer in that case. That said, I _did_ test my answer (with a simpler command that didn't require docker, but did exercise the same shell calling conventions), and would appreciate details on how it failed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I guess I didn't do *exactly* what you wrote - with the `script/$script` - I just tried to jam all that in the same line. I expect that was the (main) issue.

Comment: Putting it all on the same line is possible, but the details are important in doing so -- need to use single quotes as the outer ones in that case, such that the `$1` and `$2` are passed through literally to the underlying shell.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to substitute variables into a generated script at all (doing this opens you up to security issues associated with shell injection). Instead, pass your script as a string literal that interrogates its argv for the arguments to use. That is, use `$1`, `$2`, etc. to refer to the server names, and pass those names as explicit arguments to the shell.

```
script='
  socat /var/run/haproxy.sock stdio <<<"set weight server/server-$1 1" && \
  socat /var/run/haproxy.sock stdio <<<"set weight server/server-$2 0"
'

sudo docker run --rm --volumes-from myhaproxy mytest/socat /bin/bash -s -c "$script" \
  _ "server-A" "server-B"
```

Note that the `_` fills in for `$0` in this case.

In other circumstances (where `sudo` weren't in use), I'd suggest using environment variables for your calling convention here; however, as whether and when they're passed through is heavily dependent on the content of `/etc/sudoers`, it's safer to avoid any such configuration dependency.

---

For folks following along (and interested in testing this answer) at home, see the following simplified form:

```
script='printf "%q\n" "$1" "$2"'
/bin/bash -s -c "$script" _ "first argument" "second argument"
```